# What set do these large grey circular pieces belong to? (possibly a Star Wars set)

Tags: set-identification, star-wars

I got these pieces in a bag full of random pieces.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6f3e.jpg]

Answer (score 4):

The decorated 10x10 dish is easy, it has only been in [7748](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=50990pb04&in=S)

Those [round corners](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=58846#T=C) aren't in that set. In light bluish gray (that you have one of in the picture), it has been 5 sets, in dark bluish gray (that you have three of in the picture) it has been in 4 sets, there are no sets that have contained that piece in both colors. You can find the list of those sets on bricklink by following a few links from the linked page about the part.

The conclusion is that there are parts from at least 3 different sets in that picture.